# FreeIPMI (ipmi-sensors) not displaying PROC/MEM sensors from HP servers

Tags: hp, ipmi, ilo, ipmitool

I am trying to monitor our physical hardware using FreeIPMI, specifically I want to be alerted on processor, memory, power supply, and disk failures for our IBM, DELL, and HP servers. Running `ipmi-sensors -h <host> -u <user> -p <pass> -D LAN_2_0` gives me what I need for our IBM and DELL servers however our HP servers are missing the processor and memory sensors. I had to upgrade the iLO 3 firmware in order to return the disk sensor information.

I have read the manpage of ipmi-sensors and have tried the following with no success:

```
ipmi-sensors -h <host> -u <user> -p <pass> -D LAN_2_0 -W discretereading
ipmi-sensors -h <host> -u <user> -p <pass> -D LAN_2_0 -r all
ipmi-sensors -h <host> -u <user> -p <pass> -D LAN_2_0 -t all
ipmi-sensors -h <host> -u <user> -p <pass> -D LAN_2_0 -g 'Processor'
ipmi-sensors -h <host> -u <user> -p <pass> -D LAN_2_0 -t 'Processor'
```

What else can I try to return processor and memory sensor information?

Comment: I appreciate that you're trying to get a cross-platform solution running, but HP ILO isn't really IPMI. You're best server with HP-specific tools, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to realize that IPMI specifies an interface to retrieve certain types of information, such as processor and memory information.  However, it is not required that any particular information be made available from a vendor.  It's likely that the motherboard you have simply does not provide that data.